# Omniture site catalyst for RDP application

Tags: rdp, adobe-analytics

Can we implement omniture site catalyst for Remote desktop login of an application like MS dynamics NAV?

There is a requirement such that adobe site catalyst had to be implemented to MS- NAV, an ERP application which is basically a console app, not web app.

MS Dynamics NAV is being accessed by Remote desktop login. Is there a way to track the hits and other features provided in Omniture site catalyst.

I hope I am clear

Answer (score 0):

There are appmeasurement libraries that can accommodate almost any situation:
http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/home/index.html#Developer

I'm not sure I understand your question, however if any one of those libraries works then it is definitely possible. There's also the data insertion API as well:
https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/documentation/data-insertion/c-data-insertion-api-overview

Between those, almost every platform, online or offline, can track data as long as image requests reach the Analytics servers.

Comment: Hi Russ, we implement the javascript of omniture in the master pages of the webapplication. How to implement for an application which is accessed using RDP?